Image doesn't change on src above media query 993px
I'm building a SPA and on one page, I have products with color icons below. When clicking on the icons, the image above should change to the color indicated by the button (using JS, onclick). It works on all media queries 992px and below. Once I hit 993px, it no longer changes the image. What am I missing?
Snippet: Light version of site with product issue
Please note: There are other formatting issues that I am aware of. I've made a lot of "experimental" changes in an effort to fix this issue.
TIA!
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="EN">

<head>
  <title>All American Mailboxes of Houston</title>
  <link href="assets/AAM.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/assets/flagcon.ico" />
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.allamericanmailboxesofhouston.com" />
  <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
  <meta charset="utf-16">
  <meta name="copyright" content="©2021 All American Mailboxes of Houston">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://allamericanmailboxesofhouston.com/assets/AAM.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="mainPage">
  <header style="text-align:center;" id="header"><img src="https://allamericanmailboxesofhouston.com/assets/AAMH.webp" id="logo"></header>
  <!-- Navbar items -->
  <div id="navlist" class="w3-hide-small navlist">
    <a href="#" id="button1" class="nav__item-text home_btn" onClick="replaceContentInContainer('mainHolderLarge', 'home');">Home</a>
    <a href="#" id="button2" class="nav__item-text products_btn" onClick="replaceContentInContainer('mainHolderLarge', 'products');">Products</a>
    <a href="#" id="button3" class="nav__item-text compat_btn" onClick="replaceContentInContainer('mainHolderLarge', 'compatibility');">Compatibility</a>
    <a href="#" id="button4" class="nav__item-text contact_btn" onClick="replaceContentInContainer('mainHolderLarge', 'contact');">Contact Us</a>
  </div>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-xxlarge w3-hover-theme w3-hide-medium w3-hide-large" onclick="openSidebar()" id="open" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display:block;">&#9776;</button>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-xxlarge w3-hover-theme w3-hide-medium w3-hide-large" style="display:none; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" onclick="" id="close">&#9776;</button>
  <nav class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-card w3-hide-medium w3-hide-large" style="width:100%; display: none; position:static !important;" id="mySidebar">
    <div class="nav__content" style="width:100%">
      <span onclick="" class="w3-button w3-display-topright w3-xlarge w3-hide-medium w3-hide-large">X</span>
      <a href="#" id="button5" class="nav__item-text home_btn" onClick="replaceContentInContainer('mainHolder', 'home');">Home</a>
      <a href="#" id="button6" class="nav__item-text products_btn" onClick="replaceContentInContainer('mainHolder', 'products');">Products</a>
      <a href="#" id="button7" class="nav__item-text compat_btn" onClick="replaceContentInContainer('mainHolder', 'compatibility');">Compatibility</a>
      <a href="#" id="button8" class="nav__item-text contact_btn" onClick="replaceContentInContainer('mainHolder', 'contact');">Contact Us</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div id="mainHolder" class="w3-content w3-padding-8 w3-hide-large" name="main" style="height: auto;">
    <!-- <div onClick="screen()" id="screen" style="border:solid 1pt black; margin-top:10vh; z-index:10000;">CLICK HERE</div>-->
    <p style="font-size: 1.5rem; text-align: justify;">Content removed for brevity</p>
  </div>
  <div id="mainHolderLarge" class="w3-content w3-padding-32 w3-hide-small w3-hide-medium" name="mainLarge" style="height: auto;">
    <p style="font-size: 1.5rem; text-align: justify;">Content removed for brevity</p>
  </div>

  <!--Holds home page content to swap into mainHolders -->
  <div id="home" class="w3-content w3-padding-8 w3-hide-large" name="mainContent" style="height: auto;" hidden>
    <p style="font-size: 1.5rem; text-align: justify;">Content removed for brevity</p>
  </div>

  <div class="w3-content w3-justify w3-padding-64" id="products" style="height: auto;" hidden>
    <div class="banner">
      <img src="https://allamericanmailboxesofhouston.com/images/prods/Products_Banner(1).webp" style="max-width: 100%;">
      <p style="font-size: 1.5rem; text-align: center;">We represent all major brands of apartment and commercial mailboxes in the industry. All of our products are approved by the U.S. Postal Service, and we proudly service mailboxes throughout the State of Texas</p>
    </div>    
    <div class="CBU" id="CBU">
      <h2 style="">Cluster Box Unit (CBU) Pedestal Mailboxes</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>For outdoor centralized mail delivery</li>
        <li>CBU Pedestal mailboxes include 3 keys per tenant</li>
        <li>Engraved doors available</li>
        <li>Six types of CBU’s to meet tenant compartment and parcel locker needs</li>
        <li>Available in Sandstone, Black, Dark Bronze, Postal Grey, Forest Green, and White</li>
      </ul>
      <img loading="lazy" src="https://allamericanmailboxesofhouston.com/images/prods/CBU/CBU_WH.webp" alt="Color Previews" id="CBU_WH" />
      <img loading="lazy" src="https://allamericanmailboxesofhouston.com/images/prods/CBU/CBU_BK.webp" alt="Color Previews" id="CBU_BK" style="display:none;" />
      <img loading="lazy" src="https://allamericanmailboxesofhouston.com/images/prods/CBU/CBU_DB.webp" alt="Color Previews" id="CBU_DB" style="display:none;" />
      <img loading="lazy" src="https://allamericanmailboxesofhouston.com/images/prods/CBU/CBU_FG.webp" alt="Color Previews" id="CBU_FG" style="display:none;" />
      <img loading="lazy" src="https://allamericanmailboxesofhouston.com/images/prods/CBU/CBU_PG.webp" alt="Color Previews" id="CBU_PG" style="display:none;" />
      <img loading="lazy" src="https://allamericanmailboxesofhouston.com/images/prods/CBU/CBU_SD.webp" alt="Color Previews" id="CBU_SD" style="display:none;" />
      <div style="background-color: #f0f0f0;">
        <button type="button" onclick="changeColor('CBU_WH')" style="background-image: url('images/prods/CBU/WH.webp')" id="CBUWHbutton"></button>
        <button type="button" onClick="changeColor('CBU_BK')" style="background-image: url('images/prods/CBU/BK.webp')" id="CBUBKbutton"></button>
        <button type="button" onclick="changeColor('CBU_DB')" style="background-image: url('images/prods/CBU/DB.webp')" id="CBUDBbutton"></button>
        <button type="button" onclick="changeColor('CBU_FG')" style="background-image: url('images/prods/CBU/FG.webp')" id="CBUFGbutton"></button>
        <button type="button" onclick="changeColor('CBU_PG')" style="background-image: url('images/prods/CBU/PG.webp')" id="CBUPGbutton"></button>
        <button type="button" onclick="changeColor('CBU_SD')" style="background-image: url('images/prods/CBU/SD.webp')" id="CBUSDbutton"></button>
      </div>
    </div>    
    <img src="https://allamericanmailboxesofhouston.com/images/prods/Prods_Bottom_Banner.webp" style="max-width: 95%; margin-top: 15%; margin-bottom: -17%;">
  </div>
  <div class="w3-content w3-justify w3-padding-64" id="compatibility" style="height: auto;" hidden>
    Content removed for brevity
  </div>
  <div class="w3-content w3-justify w3-padding-64" id="contact" style="height: auto;" hidden>
   Content removed for brevity
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>


Can you please include all the information, needed to understand your question, here in the question itself? Your website will change, and make the question here incomprehensible in the future. I understand that you just want an answer, but Stack Overflow is also used by others, who have the same problem, to find a solution. Having a complete question is then essential for them to understand what exactly is asked. See also: How do I ask a good question? There's also a benefit to you: By trying to isolate the problem you might even solve it yourself.

As for your question: You seem to have multiple sets of the same images in your code, all with the same ID. Your javascript only manipulates the first set, which apparently is shown when the viewport width is less than 992 pixels and hidden when the viewport gets wider. Remember ID's have to be unique, only a CLASS can be reused multiple times.

I've checked my code a few times and I don't see any duplicate IDs. I've also tried my best to include a barebones CodePen that shows only one product and included the HTML above.

I agree that when looking in your raw HTML there are no repeated ID's, but you use quite a bit of Javascript in which you also copy HTML from one place to another. That probably causes the duplication of ID's. Have you ever use your browser's developer tools? You can use its inspector to see what Javascript has done to your HTML.

I didn't even finish reading your comment before I realized where my error was! I am a seasoned developer so yes, I've used dev tools... but I have no idea how I overlooked this for the hours I spent troubleshooting. I was indeed copying from one div to the next, and causing duplication of IDs. I have changed them to classes and it ll works now. Thanks!

You don't need to write JavaScript code yourself with W3E (W3.CSS w/JavaScript) just add w3e-slider to the container element. The W3E will assign the click events automagically.
Check this example on CodePen: https://codepen.io/emnawer/pen/zYVZOwm
<div class="w3-content w3e-slider" style=" position: relative;">
  <img class="w3-animate-opacity w3e-slide w3-show" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/10/24/15/08/sky-501350_960_720.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
  <img class="w3-animate-opacity w3e-slide" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/06/06/11/21/cape-robin-chat-3457709_960_720.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
  <img class="w3-animate-opacity w3e-slide" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/03/18/01/35/dahlia-4942346_960_720.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
  <a class="w3-button w3-hover-dark-grey" style="position: absolute; top: 45%; left: 0px;">❮</a>
  <a class="w3-button w3-hover-dark-grey" style="position: absolute; top: 45%; right: 0px;">❯</a>

</div>

It utilities W3E (W3.CSS w/JavaScript): https://w3e.uk

Thanks. I'm a JavaScript developer so I like to write it out myself. I've done this layout on  few other sites, just having an off week I guess :)

@ChrisG welcome back :)
If you have some spare time, I could really use your help.
